# java -cp Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, groovy, jar, classpath

I have a jar with the following structure

```
myJar.jar > com.company.department.mainClass.class
```

I'm trying to run it with

```
java -cp D:\directory\directory2\*.jar; com.company.department.mainClass
```

My main class does contain a main method, and I can run it in Eclipse just fine before exporting it as a jar. It's compiled from Groovy, but I don't *think* that should matter.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        ...
    }
```

And it's throwing me a "Could not find or load main class". This is on windows. What's wrong with what I'm doing?

Comment: *.jar? try full name

Comment: Post your mainClass.java

Comment: Try only "java -cp D:\directory\directory2\\* com.company.department.mainClass"

Comment: No luck there @Konrad

Comment: Are you sure mainClass.java contains `package com.company.department;`?

Comment: @VGR Yes it does. The jar is compiled from Groovy actually, but I'm pretty sure that doesn't matter once I have a jar.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 java -cp D:\directory\directory2\*.jar com.company.department.mainClass
```

Note there isn't a semicolon.

From [Wikipeda](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_%28Java%29):

> on Windows, the directory structure has a Windows syntax, and each file path must be separated by a semicolon (";").